# Barracuda 660 WAF SNMP - Barracuda-BWS::totalAttacks

Tags: snmp, barracuda, web-application-firewall

I've come across a little problem with retrieving stats via SNMP from a Barracuda Web Application Firewall 660.

According to both [the documentation](https://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/downloads/Admin_Guides/Barracuda_Web_App_Firewall_AG7.6_US.pdf) (page 211), and the MIB defination, doing an SNMP GET on the OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.20632.8.4 (*Barracuda-BWS::totalAttacks*) should retrieve the "Count of attacks in last one hour".

However, it looks to be instead returning the *total ever attacks*.

I've not come across any mention of this bug online, and barracuda themselves don't seem to be interested in correcting it. The devices are patched up-to-date.

**Can anyone else confirm they see the issue, or have resolved it in the past?**

(I know I can calculate the last hour's value via the total, however it would be much nicer to get the value directly into our monitoring setup without the intermediate step).

Comment: I know this is a little old, but this is what we have discovered too: totalAttacks is all-time, despite the documentation.  They say they have done some improvements to SNMP in v7.7 of the firmware, but I can't seem to download the MIB off the device any more